# How to format and display date without time zone?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So this is how I get the date time:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  console.log("Time: "+moment(response[i].feeding_1).format("hh:mm A"))
}
```

How can I display it as 06:00 AM?

I tried with moment js, but didn't work quite well like this:

```
console.log("Time: "+moment(response[i].feeding_1).format("hh:mm A"))
```

I get invalid date for this..

also in HTML i did this:

```
<td>
  <div>{{pen.feeding_1 | date: 'hh:mm a'}}</div>
</td>
```

Sorry for lack of code

Comment: The format it's correct, probably the date that you are passing it's not an actual date, you don't get an error or something, try passing new Date() as your date and see if that actually works.

Comment: If your app already uses momentJS, change your `moment(time)` into `moment(time, format)`, e.g. `moment(response[i].feeding_1, 'HH:mm:ssZ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get a string of format `'06:00:00Z'` and you need another string (`'06:00 AM'`) as the output, you may skip go messing with date types, libraries and timezones, simply doing `String.prototype.replace()`:

```js
const src = '06:00:00Z',

      result = src.replace(
        /^(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*/, 
        (_, hh, mm) => 
          `${hh > 12 ? +hh-12 : hh}:${mm} ${hh>=12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`)
          
console.log(result)
```